# Sending key Combinations to Serial Port ("ctrl+r") in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

Im sending commands to my serial device, like so:

```
SerialPort.write("Q")
```

Now lets say I wanted to send a key combination to my device, such as "Ctrl + R".

I've already tried:

```
SerialPort.write(keys.control AndAlso keys.R)
```

But it does not send the right keys to my device. Am I doing it wrong? If so, what is the right approach.

Thanks

Comment: What is CTRL + R ? to Terminate a process to your terminal ?

Comment: Ohhh okay i know that you want use this                                 tSerialCom.Write(New Byte() {3}, 0, 1)

Comment: I actually thought about doing it like that but never thought it would be so simple haha. anyways, I used serialport1.write(New Byte(){18}, 0,1) because {3} represents Ctrl + C. Thanks :)

Comment: @DylandeStPern, can you put that as an answer and accept it, so this question shows up as answered?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the answer:

```
serialport1.write(New Byte(){18}, 0,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Key <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>:

```
oCom.Write(New Byte() {5}, 0, 1)
```